# saveAndClose() throwing a service unavailable

Tags: google-apps-script

So my entire code is doing this:

-copy a gdoc

-delete table of contents (if found)

-delete paragraph with text "t
able of contents" (which is left over after you remove the table of contents itself)

-grab info as PDF blob

-write pdf blob to new folder.

My problem is that the "grab info as pdf blob" is getting the pre deletion version. If I run the code using my gdoc after the original run it works fine and the TOC has been removed, but if I do it immediately, it will somehow be using the pre-edit version of the document to convert.

Things I've tried:

- changing my element.removeFromParent() to element.clear() // still
  getting the unedited pdf
- moving the gdocToPDF conversion  to its own
  function // still getting the unedited pdf
- adding a 10 second wait
  BEFORE calling that function // still getting the unedited pdf
- saveAndClose() before calling gdocToPDF // throwing a service
  documents failed error

Now hypothetically I could make all my temp copies and edit them, and then go back and do the pdfs later, but I'd really like to get this done in one shot and delete each temp as I go along.

Is there any reason that I can access the document just fine in .getId() but not saveAndClose()? it was available from the type ahead. My changes do take in the gdoc itself, so its not that I've done something illegal to the document (I don't think

```
  var copyId = testdoc.getId(); // WORKS
  testdoc.saveAndClose(); // throws the error
  gdocToPdf(tempFolder,copyId);
```

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that e.clear() was what was messing me up. I tried reverting my deletions to e.removeFromParent() and suddenly my saveAndClose works!

Posting this because I spent 20 minutes writing up my question and the answer ended up being something different from the similar questions.